# Can I use `tf.layers.conv3d` with different image sizes? Use 'None' instead of a fix integer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

The following script does not work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 
input = np.ones((1,1, 3,50,50))
t_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,1,3,None,50), name='input')
# t_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1,1,3,50,50), name='input')
t_conv3d = tf.layers.conv3d(
    inputs=t_ph,
    filters=48,
    kernel_size=[3,3,3],
    data_format='channels_first',
    activation=tf.nn.relu
)

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.global_variables_initializer()])

    should_fail = t_conv3d.eval(feed_dict={t_ph: input})
    print "should_fail ", should_fail.shape
```

Error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Is it possible to have a conv3d with the parameter 'None' instead of an integer?

Comment: Do you mean that you have inputs of different sizes in a single batch? If yes, one practical approach is to pad them to the same size. If not, then is there any problem of directly feeding them without using placeholder?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to pad them...

Comment: Can you show a full stack trace of the error you're getting?